# Mercurial authenticated pushing problem

Tags: mercurial

We have central repository via http on Apache with digest authentication for two users 'One' and 'Two'.

User 'One' can do:

```
    hg commit -uTwo -mText
    hg push http://central-repo/hg/project
```

How to prevent that fake on the central repository?
Or how to know who makes that push to the central repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying Mercurial Changesets are from who they say they're from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284642/verifying-mercurial-changesets-are-from-who-they-say-theyre-from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a pushlog extension to keep track of who pushes what. See the Mozilla hgpoller repo for the pushlog extension they use (they have a separate set of templates as well). An alternative solution would be to write a hook to deny pushing changesets authored by someone else than the authenticating user. Since that can also be a very valid scenario, the pushlog solution might be best.

- http://hg.mozilla.org/users/bsmedberg_mozilla.com/hgpoller
- http://hg.mozilla.org/hg_templates/