# Mercurial user management and security

Tags: security, mercurial

I have just installed Mercurial 1.9.3 on my Centos 5.5 x64 server. I'm publishing my repositories using `hgweb.wsgi` and with `mod_wsgi`.

This server is only for use by our internal codebase and development team so I've also protected my server using `.htaccess` and basic HTTP authentication. This is all good and I can clone repositories to local and push changes back to the central repo(s).

There is one thing I'm not understanding correctly which is how to control and manage users.

For example, I have two users in my central repository server `.htpassword` file: `bob` and `kevin`.

On each of `bob` and `kevin`'s local machines they have their own Mercurial `.hgrc` files with their `username` settings configured.

However these `.hgrc` users appear to have no relation at all to the user's specified in the remote server's `.htpassword` file.

This means that I can end up with pushes to the central repository coming from "Mickey Mouse" and "Donald Duck" which isn't useful.

How do I enforce end to end mapping of the local `.hgrc` username to the `.htpassword` user to maintain, i.e. ensure that the user specified in `.hgrc` matches the `.htpassword` user?

Comment: You'll need a hook for this. The username in Mercurial is indeed entirely separate from whatever authentication you have on your server. For instance, you could clone one of my repositories, make some changes and commit, and give me a pull request, which I execute, and push back into my own repository. This is legal, because *I*'m doing the pushing, but it's your changesets I'm pushing. If you want to prohibit this type of thing, you'll need a hook, but unfortunately I don't have the details so I'm just leaving a comment for now.

Comment: And... what you can prohibit is someone pushing changes with invalid usernames to the server, you cannot prohibit someone from committing changesets with the wrong username to begin with, because all that happens locally.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - thanks for the advice - I think I get it now. Spent a couple of weeks now getting my head around DVCS concepts and the lights have finally come on :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying Mercurial Changesets are from who they say they're from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284642/verifying-mercurial-changesets-are-from-who-they-say-theyre-from)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it's worth saying: **Everyone worries about this at first, but in practice it's just not a problem**.

At the time a user is committing with a DVCS, be it Mercurial, git, or other, they're not necessarily connected to any authentication/authorization system you control, so their commits are necessarily committed (locally) with whatever authorship info they want to assert.  You can later reject those changesets upon `push` to a repo/server you control, but that will be a big hassle for you and for them.  It's not just a matter of re-intering their name/password they have to alter the history of that changeset and all subsequent changesets to change that authorship information.

The list of completely unsatisfying *solutions* to this is:

- reject pushes where changeset authorship doesn't match authenticated users using a hook (in practice this sucks because developers pull from one another and push one another's changesets all the time)
- make developers sign their changesets with the gpg extension or hgsigs (a huge hassle and they'll forget)
- keep a pushlog on the server that records the authenticated user that pushed each changeset separate from its authorship (Mozilla does this, and it's less of a hassle that than others but still not likely to ever be consulted).

If you positively can't risk bogus changesets entering a specific repo then use a human filter where people push to shared repo A and only reviewer/buildmanager/you can push from repo A to repo B, where repo B is where official builds come from.  Mercurial itself uses this system.

In the end my advice is to not worry about it.  Developers worth hiring are proud to put their name on their commits, and if you don't have developers worth hiring you're doomed to failure already.

Comment: Having knocked about with Mercurial for a couple of weeks now, I "get it" :)

Comment: Awesome.  I went through *precisely* the same process.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. I want to set up a new Mercurial server without VPN. Only employees of our company are allowed to have access to the code. I'm not worried about any difficulties that some unauthorised developer might have. He would just have to get authorised beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enforce end to end mapping of the local .hgrc username to the .htpassword user to maintain

No ways to do it. But (instead) ACL extension + ssh (hg-ssh or mercurial-server) gives more predictable results

PS

```
[ui] username =
```

usable and have sense **only** in changeset-comment context just as note, nothing more